# Classifying classifiers

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

Is there a way of exploring similarities among classifiers that have been trained on datasets that have different features?

For example: I train several linear SVMs (though it could be any classifier) to discriminate natural from manmade sounds using different datasets, and then I train a different set of linear SVMs to discriminate natural from manmade images using different datasets. Is there a way to characterize the trained SVMs such that it abstracts away from the input (sounds vs. images) to tell if they are accomplishing the classification using similar information (e.g. variance vs. intensity).

In short, is there a way to classify classifiers?